# FindControl() and nested controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, ext.net

I have this ASP code:

```
 <ext:GridPanel ID="grid">
                <ColumnModel runat="server">
                    <Columns>
                        <ext:RowNumbererColumn />
                        <ext:Column Align="Center" ColumnID="Type">
                        </ext:Column>
                    // closing tags
```

I want to get the columns object. I'm trying this:

```
var typeCol= this.grdResourceState.ColumnModel.Columns.Where(column => column.ColumnID == "Type"); // this works
var typeColRef= FindControl("grdResourceState.ColumnModel.Columns"); // this is a null
```

What do I do to make `FindControl` be able to search control children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign an id to the **ColumnModel** control and then retrieve if. Once you got it you can access the children controls:

```
<ext:GridPanel ID="grid">
                <ColumnModel runat="server" id="someId">
                    <Columns>
                        <ext:RowNumbererColumn />
                        <ext:Column Align="Center" ColumnID="Type">
                        </ext:Column>
                    // closing tags
```

Then:

```
var typeCol= this.grdResourceState.ColumnModel.Columns.Where(column => column.ColumnID == "Type"); // this works
var typeColRef= FindControl("someId");
```

[Here's more info on the FindControl method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx)